# How do I change between two Partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have two Partial views in my project. One is a LogIn partial view which is a part of my masterpage (layout) and it needs to be filled with a username and password after a button is clicked.

```
    Nickname:
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.NickName)
    </div>
    <div>
        Password:
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password)
    </div>
<button type="submit">Click to log in!</button>
```

The second one is a post partial that welcomes the user if they enter the right username and password.

How do I change between the partial views?

Answer (score 0):

Call these two `partial views` on two `<div>` tags with unique `ID`.
Check `username` and `password` using the ajax code. If it is successful, then `hide` the first partial view and `show` the second partial view, which contains the "Welcome" message.

Eg:

```
<div id ="Login">
   @Html.Action("LoginView","Account");
</div>

 <div id ="Welcome" class="hide">
   @Html.Action("WelcomeView", "Home");
 </div>
```

Script

```
$("#Login").click(function () {
   var username = $("#NickName").val();
   var password = $("#Password").val();
   $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/Login",
        data: { username: username,password:password },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if(data == true)
             {
                 $("#Welcome").addclass("show").removeclass("hide");
                 $("#Login").addclass("hide").removeclass("show");
             }
         },
        error: function (reponse) {

        }
    });
})
```